# appcmd to check a config exists?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, iis-8, appcmd, iis-logs

I can run this command to add a custom log:

```
.\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /+"[name='MyWebSite'].logFile.customFields.[logFieldName='OriginalIP',sourceName='X-FORWARDED-FOR',sourceType='RequestHeader']" /commit:apphost
```

What command to I use to see if that config has already been set? There is no `appcmd.exe get config -section...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
appcmd.exe list config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /text:*
```

Depending on what you want to check for, you will have to parse the output.

For more information, run

```
appcmd.exe /? config
```

Comment: But how can we parse this? Can we check also attribute value?